# Javascript function using "this = " gives "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype-programming, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to get a JavaScript object to use the "this" assignments of another objects' constructor, as well as assume all that objects' prototype functions. Here's an example of what I'm attempting to accomplish:

```
 /* The base - contains assignments to 'this', and prototype functions
  */
 function ObjX(a,b) {
     this.$a = a;
     this.$b = b;
 }

 ObjX.prototype.getB() {
     return this.$b;
 }

 function ObjY(a,b,c) {
    // here's what I'm thinking should work:
    this = ObjX(a, b * 12); 
    /* and by 'work' I mean ObjY should have the following properties:
     * ObjY.$a == a, ObjY.$b == b * 12,
     * and ObjY.getB == ObjX.prototype.getB
     * ... unfortunately I get the error: 
     *     Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
     */

    this.$c = c; // just to further distinguish ObjY from ObjX.
 }
```

I'd be grateful for your thoughts on how to have ObjY subsume ObjX's assignments to 'this' (i.e. not have to repeat all the `this.$* = *` assignments in ObjY's constructor) and have ObjY assume ObjX.prototype.

My first thought is to try the following:

```
function ObjY(a,b,c) {
   this.prototype = new ObjX(a,b*12);
}
```

Ideally I'd like to learn how to do this in a prototypal way (i.e. not have to use any of those 'classic' OOP substitutes like [Base2](http://code.google.com/p/base2/)).

It may be noteworthy that ObjY will be anonymous (e.g. `factory['ObjX'] = function(a,b,c) { this = ObjX(a,b*12); ... }`) -- if I've the terminology right.

Thank you.

Comment: related: [Why can't I assign a new value to “this” in a prototype function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9713323/1048572)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't really do that, because the [`this`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.7) value by definition is *immutable*, you can't change in that way what it references to.

A workaround would be to use the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) methods to run your `ObjX` constructor function in the `this` object of `ObjY`:

```
function ObjY(a,b,c) {
  ObjX.call(this, a, b * 12); 
  this.$c = c;
}
```

In the above example, the `ObjX` function is executed changing its `this` value, so all property extensions you make to that object in this function, will be reflected in the new object that the `this` value refers in the `ObjY` constructor.

As soon the `call` method ends, the `this` object will be augmented and you can make more property extensions, like adding your `$c` value.

**Edit:** About the prototypes, your sample will not work, because the `prototype` property has no special meaning for object in stances it will be just as any other property, it should be used on *constructor functions*.

I think you might be confusing the `prototype` property of constructors with the internal `[[Prototype]]` property that all objects have.

The `[[Prototype]]` property can only be set by the `new` operator (through the [`[[Construct]]`](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php) internal operation), this property can't be changed, (although some implementations, like the Mozilla one, you can access it through `obj.__proto__;`, and in [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php), the `Object.getPrototypeOf` method has been introduced, but I wouldn't recommend you to mess directly with it).

Actually, when your constructor function is executed, the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of the object that the `this` value refers, has already been set to its constructor's `prototype` property.

So, as @Anurag comments, you could set the `ObjY.prototype` to a newly created `ObjX` object:

```
function ObjY(a,b,c) {
  ObjX.call(this, a, b * 12); 
  this.$c = c;
}

ObjY.prototype = new ObjX();
ObjY.prototype.constructor = ObjY;
```

That will make that your `ObjY` inherit also the properties added to the `ObjX.prototype`, and as you see, I changed the `ObjY.prototype.constructor`, since the assignment in the line above will make this property to wrongly point to `ObjX`.

Recommended articles:

- [Constructors considered mildly confusing](http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html)
- [JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance](http://www.3site.eu/doc/)

Comment: Thank you CMS. Great link, too. The other question is how to assign the prototypes - can that be done from within the constructor?

Comment: @Brian, set an object of ObjX as the prototype for ObjY, to get its methods too. `ObjY.prototype = new ObjX;`. Methods and properties if not found in the current object, are looked up in the prototype chain.

Comment: @Anurag, thank you. Can one do that within the constructor (since the constructor is anonymous)? i.e. `function ObjY() { this.prototype = new ObjX(); }`?

Comment: The second link has broken, but (over ten years later) the "Constructors" article tied the loose ends together for me brilliantly (which admittedly might not have been true if I hadn't already been exposed to many related articles, such as [javascript.info/function-prototype](https://javascript.info/function-prototype)).