# Why can't I assign a new value to "this" in a prototype function?

Tags: javascript

Why can I do this:

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
    this.splice(0, this.length);
    return this.concat([1,2,3]);
}
```

But I can't do this:

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
    return this = [1,2,3];
}
```

Both functions destroy the value of this and change it to `[1,2,3]` but the second one throws the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

I suspect it's because allowing assignment means I could potentially change the array to something else (like a string), but I'm hoping someone out there knows for sure and/or has a more detailed explanation.

Comment: What effect would you expect "assignment to `this`" to have on the caller?

Comment: I would expect it to modify the caller the same way that `Array.push` modifies its caller.

Comment: But `Array.push` doesn't change which object `this` points to, it just modifies the data *inside* the object. What you're suggesting is that you reassign `this` to point to another object entirely. You've got the right idea by realising that assigning a string to `this` would be confusing, but the same applies for assigning *any* other distinct object to `this`. The caller won't have any idea what happened, since you can't change all the caller's references to the object you just swapped in.

Comment: @GregHewgill is right. `Array.push` is saying "here, add some sprinkles to my donut". Actually assigning something totally different to `this` is like saying, "no wait, I want _that_ donut," and you can't do that.  `this` is an immutable donut.

Comment: @ThomasShields: until it's eaten

Comment: @qwertymk hm, yes, perhaps donuts weren't the best analogy. In retrospect, I should have used [waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/404).

Comment: @ThomasShields: 404's always leave a bad taste in my mouth

Comment: @qwertymk I intentionally linked to the 404 cuz it had waffles. :)

Comment: @ThomasShields: I realized 8-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not permitted to assign a value to `this` within a function. Suppose that you *could* do this, and your code looked something like:

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
    return this = [1, 2, 3];
}

var a = ["beans", "rice"];
a.foo();
// a now points to an object containing [1, 2, 3]
```

Now, what if you did this:

```
var a = ["beans", "rice"];
var b = a; // b refers to the same object as a
b.foo();
// what does b refer to now? how about a?
```

The act of calling a function `.foo()` on an object should not change the *identity* of the object. This would be very confusing for the caller if `b` suddenly started referring to a different object than `a` simply because some method was called.

Answer (score 25):

You're confusing objects with references.

An array is an object, when you use a literal like `[1,2,3]` you're making a new array.

A variable name like `this` or `a` is a reference to an object. If it helps, imagine an object as a person, and the reference as their nickname. You can have more than one reference to the same object, for example:

```
var a = [1,2];
var b = a;
b.push(3);
alert(a.length); // Gives "3"
```

Imagine if you had a friend named Sarah. You also sometimes call her "Ace". If Sarah gets a haircut one day, Ace has a haircut too, because "Sarah" and "Ace" are both different names for the same person.

If you use a mutating array method like `a.push` or `a.splice` (`concat` however is not one!), you change the existing Array object, and `a` still refers to the same object. This is like getting a hair cut - you may look different, but you're still the same person.

When you assign a reference to a new value, with `a = [1,2,3]`, you're creating a new array, and changing `a` to refer to it. This is like finding a new friend with different hair, and deciding to call her Ace instead.

Now `this` is a special name generated by Javascript. It's not a given name like Sarah, but more of a title, like "mother". Your mother can get a new haircut, but you can't get a new mother. Likewise, you can't change what `this` refers to from inside a function.

Answer (score 9):

You are not allowed to re-assign `this`. Because the **this** value associated with an execution context is immutable.

Answer (score 3):

**Is it possible to change the value of `this`?** Not by assignment, you cannot assign a value to `this`

Your case:

> ```
> Array.prototype.foo = function() {
>     this.splice(0, this.length);
>     return this.concat([1,2,3]);
> }
> ```
>
> But I can't do this:
>
> ```
> Array.prototype.foo = function() {
>     return this = [1,2,3];
> }
> ```

When you modify the prototype adding method `foo()`, the first part makes the array become empty, equals to reassign its instance.

For example to `var a = []`

Then in the return value:

```
return this.concat([1,2,3]);
```

Remember that `concat` does not destroys an array, it creates a new array and returns it

Given `a = ['x']` and `b = ['y']`, `c = a.concat(b)` results in `c = ['x','y']`, and `a` and `b` remain the same as they were

Now since you are doing this inside the array

```
a=['a','b','c']
```

then you call `a.foo();`, inside `a` will get equal `a=[]`, with `this.splice(0, this.length);` then will concatenate `[ ]` with `[1,2,3]`

So if I say just `a.foo()`, in fact nothing happens outside if I do not assign the result to something, just a remains empty.

If `a` is assigned to something

```
c = a.foo()
```

then `c` will be `[1,2,3]`, and `a` still empty `[ ]`

In the second part, `this = [1,2,3]`

It is possible to change the value of this?, not by assignment, you cannot assign a value to this