# Remove first occurrence of a letter from a string object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to extend the javascript string functionality for a project, I want to be able to have a function to remove the first occurrence of a string by a function.
JS does not allow to change the text withing a function of string function.

error I believe is trying to assign a text to 'this'.

Please help let me know if there's another way to implement this.
Thanks

```js
// remove first occurrence of a letter from a string
String.prototype.removeFirstMatch = function(char){
 var text = '';
 for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
  if(this[i] == char){
   text = this.slice(0, i) + this.slice(i + 1, this.length);
  }
 }
 this = text;
}

var word = 'apple';

word.removeFirstMatch('p');

console.log(word);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Javascript are immutable.   That means you can't change the contents of a string object.  So, something like `.slice()` does not actually modify a string, it returns a new string.

So, your `.removeFirstMatch()`  method needs to return a new string because it can't modify the current string object.

You also cannot assign to `this` in Javascript.

Here's a version that returns a new string:

```js
// remove first occurrence of a letter from a string
String.prototype.removeFirstMatch = function(char) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this.charAt(i) == char) {
            return this.slice(0, i) + this.slice(i + 1, this.length);
        }
    }
    return this;
}

var word = 'apple';
var newWord = word.removeFirstMatch('p');
document.write(newWord);
```

Note: I also put `var` in front if `i` to make it a local variable rather than an implicit global and to allow it to run in `strict` mode.  And, I returned out of the `for` loop as soon as the first match was found rather than continuing to loop.  And, it returns the new string, or if no changes made, it returns the original.

---

This could be cleaned up a bit to this:

```js
// remove first occurrence of a letter from a string
String.prototype.removeFirstMatch = function(char) {
    var found = this.indexOf(char);
    if (found !== -1) {
        return this.slice(0, found) + this.slice(found + 1);
    }
    return this;
}

var word = 'apple';
var newWord = word.removeFirstMatch('p');
document.write(newWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in javascript are immutable (you can't change a string...but you can reassign a string...)

Also, you can't change the value of `this` within a function.  See @TobiasCohen's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713323/why-cant-i-assign-a-new-value-to-this-in-a-prototype-function).

But, you could *return* the updated value, and reassign `word` to the returned value...

```
String.prototype.removeFirstMatch = function(char){
  var text = '';
  for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    if(this[i] == char){
        text = this.slice(0, i) + this.slice(i + 1, this.length);
    }
  }
  return text;
}
var word = 'apple';
word = word.removeFirstMatch('p');
console.log(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable (you cannot modify a string). However you can do this:

```
String.prototype.removeFirstMatch = function(char){
var text = '';
for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
  if(this[i] == char){
    text = this.slice(0, i) + this.slice(i + 1, this.length);
  }
}
return text;
}
 var word = 'apple';
 newWord = word.removeFirstMatch('p');
 console.log(newWord);
```