# How to change javascript string value when referenced by "this"

Tags: javascript

When "this" refers to a javascript string object, is there any way to change the value of "this"?

```
this = "abc";
```

Complains about an illegal left-side assignment.

EDIT: For clarification, I am attempting the following, but it looks like there will be no way to accomplish this.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (find, replace) {
    while (this.indexOf(find) > -1) {
        this = this.replace(find, replace); // illegal
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error says, you cannot change the value of `this` (i.e. assign to it).

Comment: you cannot change what `this` is equivalent to. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)[Here is MDN] talking about it

Comment: Related: [Why can't I assign a new value to “this” in a prototype function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9713323/218196)

Comment: FYI: this looks like it could be done with `return this.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);`

Comment: Thanks Felix.  That was helpful.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Every string method returns a new string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You can never assign a value to `this`, and strings are immutable.

If you want to overwrite the value of the variable that provided the context for `this` then you have to access it by name.