# Mass-assign to multiple Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm actually looking for a working answer, similar to destructuring (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

But I've seen this sample:

```
[a, b] = [1, 2];
```

So I was hoping if there's a way to do mass-assigning for multiple object properties, like this:

```
this.[name, age, is_male] = [ 'John Doe', 22, true ];
```

To shorten this:

```
this.name = 'John Doe';
this.age = 22;
this.is_male = true;
```

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713323/why-cant-i-assign-a-new-value-to-this-in-a-prototype-function#answer-9713442

Answer (score 6):

One less-than-perfect option is:

```
const [name, age, is_male] = ['John Doe', 22, true];
Object.assign(this, {name, age, is_male});
```

or

```
Object.assign(this, 
  ([name, age, is_male]) => ({name, age, is_male}))(['John, Doe', 22, true]));
```

Neither of these seems better than the three assignment statements.

What you are trying to do is to destructure into an object (in this case, one that you can `assign` to `this`. Various syntaxes have been proposed for this, such as

```
Object.assign(this,
  { [name, age, is_male] = ['John Doe', 22, true] });
```

and

```
Object.assign(this,
  ['John Doe', 22, true].{name, age, is_male});
```

but they have not gotten much traction in the language standards process.

Comment: Only first option is working, other three stements cause respectively: `Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ')'`, `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ] in computed property name`, `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing name after . operator`

Answer (score 2):

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will do that.

```js
var obj = {
  foo: 1,
  copy: function() {
    Object.assign(this, {
      name: "John Doe",
      age: 22,
      is_male: true
    });
  }
}

obj.copy();
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do

```
this.[...
```

since this will give you an

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

but you can use the `[]`s to assign `this.`-values:

```
[this.name, this.age, this.is_male] = ['John Doe', 22, true];
```

Comment: Are you using it from inside of an object? On JSFiddle it worked perfectly.