# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment when really assigning a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, variable-assignment

Why does this snippet in node (10.5)

```
    .then(function() {
      this = {...this, ...payload};
      this.update();
      resolve({ok:true, node});
    });
```

gives the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

the payload holds a few properties that need to be added to `this` or if the property exists the property needs to be updated.

I do not understand why there is this error :(

Comment: You cannot assign `this`. Some more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713323/why-cant-i-assign-a-new-value-to-this-in-a-prototype-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the Error is staightforward and says `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`, it means that you are using a wrong element in the left hand side of your assignment.

And that's because you are writing `this = {...this, ...payload};`, where you were trying to write a value to  [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in tour function, ***which is wrong and not possible***, because you can't change `this` and assign a value to it as it's not permitted in JavaScript.

If you check the [MDN **this** Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) you can see that:

> In most cases, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. **It can't be set by assignment during execution**, and it may be different each time the function is called.

Comment: I see makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can assign this directly because it has alot of inner non-enumerable properties and other types of hidden stuff, what we can use is use Object.assign

```
.then(function(){
      Object.assign(this,payload)
      this.update();
      resolve({ok:true, node});
    });
```