# Assign parameters to new object in ES5 constructor using spread operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

A constructor is accepting an options object with multiple properties. How can I assign them to the newly created object without specifying each one?

Here is my failed attempt

```
function Client(options) {
    const defaultOptions = { 
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 1905,
        loggerFn: console.log,
        maxTime: 60000, 
        startFromTransactionId: 1 
    };
    this = { ...defaultOptions, ...userOptions, ...this }
}
```

> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

I think this works, but I hope there is a simpler solution using spread operators

```
function Client(options) {
    const defaultOptions = { 
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 1905,
        loggerFn: console.log,
        maxTime: 60000, 
        startFromTransactionId: 1 
    };

    for (prop in defaultOptions) {
        if (defaultOptions.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            this[prop] = options[prop] ? options[prop] : defaultOptions[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You tried to assign to `this` inside a function, which I don't think is legal (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713323/why-cant-i-assign-a-new-value-to-this-in-a-prototype-function)). But have you tried `Object.assign(this, {...defaultOptions, ...userOptions})`?

Comment: @SamiHult that's an answer, and a good one. You should post it as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Object.assign` should do the trick:

```
function Client(userOptions) {
    const defaultOptions = { 
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 1905,
        loggerFn: console.log,
        maxTime: 60000, 
        startFromTransactionId: 1 
    };
    Object.assign(this, { ...defaultOptions, ...userOptions });
}
```