# Creating a unit conversion method for the number prototype

Tags: javascript, numbers, prototype

I am currently trying to create a unit conversion for metric and English scale as a method for the number prototype. Heres my code:

```
Number.prototype.UnitConversion = function (units){
    switch (units){
        case "Metric":
            this = this/100;
            return this;
        case "English":
            this = this/12;
            return this;
    }
}
var a = 5;
alert(a.UnitConversion("Metric"))
```

However I get a left side invalid argument error. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Its because an unexpected assignment to `this`. Maybe try a more readable, clean solution? Something like this:

```js
Number.prototype.UnitConversion = function (units){
    let conversion;
    switch (units){
        case "Metric":
            conversion = this/100;
            break;
        case "English":
            conversion = this/12;
            break;
        //always add a default case
    }

    return conversion;
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Why is the default case necessary^

Comment: Because its a "safety fallback". Imagine someone for some reason passes "Facebook" as unit, your code doesnt know how to deal with it, cause you have only 2 cases. It will return undefined unless you define a default.

Answer (score 0):

**this** is immutable in JavaScript, meaning you cannot reassign it, see: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713323/why-cant-i-assign-a-new-value-to-this-in-a-prototype-function). However, you could simply return the value of some calculation done on it:

```js
Number.prototype.UnitConversion = function(units) {
    switch (units){
        case "Metric":
            return this/100;
            
        case "English":
            return this/12;
            
        default:
            return;
    }
}
var a = 5;
console.log(a.UnitConversion("Metric"))
```