# can't use "this" on both sides of assignment

Tags: javascript

I want to make my function `addHat()` reusable for other person objects as well, so I decided to use `this` instead of exact name of the person and pass my other objects as `this` by `addHat.call()` and `addHat.apply()` methods.

ie. I want to shallow copy the person object using spread (having new references for all of the properties.

However, it doesn't work using `this` on both sides of the assignment

```js
let person1 = {
    a: "a",
    hats: [],
  gloves: []
};

function addHat(newHat, ...params) {
    this = {
        ...this,
        hats: [...this.hats, newHat, ...params],
    };
}

addHat.call(person1, "hatA");
console.log(person1.hats);
```

But perfectly works when using the name directly instead:

```js
let person1 = {
    a: "a",
    hats: [],
  gloves: []
};


function addHat(newHat, ...params) {
  person1 = {
    ...person1,
        hats: [...person1.hats, newHat, ...params],
    };
}

addHat.apply("uselessThis", ["hatA", "hatB"]);
console.log(person1.hats);
```

Can you help me to make this function reusable with the current format? (using spread and shallow copying of the object properties)

every hint or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: basically, `this` is read-only but not immutable, so you can do `this.hats = ...`

Comment: As you have found out, you can't assign to `this` in a function, but I'm not sure why you are trying to. Couldn't you just do `this.hats = [/*...*/]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I assign a new value to "this" in a prototype function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713323/why-cant-i-assign-a-new-value-to-this-in-a-prototype-function)

Comment: @Aioros the problem is: I want to change all of the object properties' references, I don't want to copy properties like gloves by reference.

Comment: @Liam Well, no. good to know the concept, but I want to get my current method to work also.

Comment: If you really need to do that, then you will have to loop through the properties and change them.

Comment: @Aioros Isn't there a shorter way using spread? I want to shorten it is as much as possible.

Comment: @Apolo, well yes, but no. I want to change the person's property's references as well.

Comment: Kind feels like a misunderstanding of spread i.e. "allows an iterable" from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax and the strict mode regarding "this" re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that it's easier if you pass persona as an argument of the function.

Try to avoid the use of this in js because it can become tricky to debug

```js
let person1 = {
  a: "a",
  hats: [],
  gloves: []
};

function immutableAddHat(person, ...newHats) {
  return {
    ...person,
    hats: [...person.hats, ...newHats],
  };
}

function addHat(...newHats) {
  Object.entries(this).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    this[k] = v
  })

  this.hats = [...this.hats, ...newHats]

}

const newPerson1 = immutableAddHat(person1, "hatA");

console.log(newPerson1.hats);

addHat.call(person1, "Hatb")

console.log(person1)
```

I added the method that uses this

Comment: 1) this doesn't answer the question. 2) *Try to avoid the use of this in js because it can become tricky to debug* is an incredibly silly thing to say. You can't *void this*. It's a fundamental part of js

Comment: @Liam 1) I think that it does answer the problem of reusability 2) I didn't said that you never have to use this but if you don't need it you should avoid it. I prefer to use pure function that return a new result each time because they are more predictable and easier to test.

Comment: well, I don't agree the not using `this`. even though your solution kind of solves my problem, but, I don't want to reassign the person object out of the function. I just want to call the function using `.call` `.apply` in the future.

Comment: @Hootan I edited my answer even if I prefer the immutable solution because is much more predictable

Comment: @R4ncid unfortunately your solution doesn't accomplish my goals, I want to copy all the properties by value (shallow copy), your new solution saves the old reference for `person1.gloves`.

Comment: @Hootan I miss the purpose of your request but I edited my response. I'd go with the immutable solution so you don't have all this problems.