# Why can't I set "this" to null to delete a tree node in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete a root node in a tree, and the tree has only one node.  Since "this" refers to the current context of the node, I set it to null doing `this = null;` (Case 2 of the code below).  However, I got an error msg: `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.  A way around is to use `delete this.val;` (Case 1).

My Question: Why I can't set `this = null;` to delete a tree object?  Another way to delete an obj? Thank you.

```
var BST = function(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
}

BST.prototype.remove = function(val) {
  //delete this.val;  // Case 1: OK
  this = null;        // Case 2: WRONG !
}

BST.prototype.printTree = function() {
  if (this === undefined) {
    return;
  } else
    console.log(this.val);
}

var bst = new BST(70);
bst.remove(70);
bst.printTree();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I assign a new value to "this" in a prototype function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713323/why-cant-i-assign-a-new-value-to-this-in-a-prototype-function)

Comment: You need to implement `BST.removeChild(which)` instead.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430552/javascript-function-using-this-gives-invalid-left-hand-side-in-assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a keyword in javascript and should not be on the left side of an assignment, like here (Case 2): `this = null`.

When you do `delete this.val;` (Case 1) you are removing the property `val` from whatever context that `this` represents in the scope of the function (BST, in your case, as it is a prototype function).

I believe you will need to refactor your code to perform the branch deletion using the root, or parent node, instead. Like:

```
BST.prototype.remove = function(branchToDeleteRef) {
    this[branchToDeleteRef] = null;
}
```

If you use `this.val = null` it will also work, like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fhkyge8/).

Answer (score 2):

Once all references to your object are gone, it's cleaned up. So if `this.left` and `this.right` are also trees, setting `this.left` or `this.right` to `null` will delete those trees, if there are no other references to them. To look at it another way, you delete your node by deleting it from its parent, not from itself.